# How int convert to string when String s="A"+5;

Tags: java

How is an `int` value automatically converted into a `String` when we concatenate a `String` with an `int`? For example, consider this code:

```
int i=5;
String s="A"+i;
```

The output is "A5". So, how was `i` converted into a `String` before it was concatenated with `"A"`?

Comment: I do not get your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [primitive-boolean To String concatenation/conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894892/primitive-boolean-to-string-concatenation-conversion)

Answer (score 2):

This is defined in the JLS. [Section 15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) (string concatenation operator) has:

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

[Section 5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) has:

> Any type may be converted to type String by string conversion.
>
> A value x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance creation expression (§15.9):
>
> - If T is `boolean`, then use `new Boolean(x)`.
> - If T is `char`, then use `new Character(x)`.
> - If T is `byte`, `short`, or `int`, then use `new Integer(x)`.
> - If T is `long`, then use `new Long(x)`.
> - If T is `float`, then use `new Float(x)`.
> - If T is `double`, then use `new Double(x)`.
>
> This reference value is then converted to type `String` by string conversion.
>
> Now only reference values need to be considered:
>
> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string `"null"` (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
>
> Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the `toString` method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the `toString` method is null, then the string `"null"` is used instead.

Now that's the *general* process. In the code in your *title* (`String s = "A" + 5`), this is a constant expression ([section 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)), so the compiler performs the concatenation at compile time, ensuring the result is the same as it *would* have been by following the above steps at execution time. That *doesn't* happen for the code in the *body* of your question, where you're using a variable for the `int`.

In fact, the description above only explains what the result of string concatenation should be - the compiler can (and does, in the case of the Oracle JDK) use the overloads of `StringBuilder.append` to perform the relevant conversions - it trusts that the result will be the same as performing the conversion using the above step and then appending.

To demonstrate that, compile a class containing this method:

```
public void concatenation() {
    // Declare the variable x separately so that the concatenation expression
    // is not a constant expression. (*We* know the result, but the language
    // rules don't classify it as a constant expression.)
    int x = 5;
    String y = "A" + x;
}
```

Then decompile it with `javap -c` and you'll see:

```
public void concatenation();
  Code:
     0: iconst_5      
     1: istore_1      
     2: new           #3;   // class java/lang/StringBuilder
     5: dup           
     6: invokespecial #4;   // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
     9: ldc           #5;   // String A
    11: invokevirtual #6;   // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    14: iload_1       
    15: invokevirtual #7;   // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    18: invokevirtual #8;   // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
    21: astore_2      
    22: return
```

In other words, the method is equivalent to:

```
public void concatenation() {
    int x = 5;
    StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
    tmp.append("A");
    tmp.append(x);
    String y = tmp.toString();
}
```

The *exact* details of the use of `StringBuilder` are a compiler implementation detail, however. For example, it could pass `"A"` into the `StringBuilder` constructor, or provide an expected size to the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I didn't realize type conversions could be done as part of constant folding. Neat!

Comment: Except now the code in your edit suggests that it's not a constant at all. Un-neat :( (though probably sensible)

Comment: @dlev: No, constant folding occurs when it *is* a constant expression. The code in my edit is for the case where it's *not* a constant exprdession.

Comment: Right, except the code in your non-constant example appears identical to the OPs code, about which you wrote "In your case, this is a constant expression (section 15.28), so the compiler performs the concatenation at compile time..." Thus my confusion :)

Comment: @dlev: Ah, I see. The cause for the confusion is that the OP has provided two pieces of code - one in the title (which is a constant expression) and one in the body (which isn't). Will edit to clarify.

Comment: Ah, didn't even notice the title. It all makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

If you want convert an int for example into string you can use a [String Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append(5);
String integer = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Or you can do:

```
String integer = String.valueOf(5);
```