# unable to print multiple Boolean in Kotlin

Tags: variables, types, kotlin

i'm beginning with kotlin language

```
fun main (args:Array<String>){


    var flag1:Boolean= true //Explicit declaration
    var flag2: =false //Implicit declaration

     println(flag2 + "and " + flag1)

     println(flag1)
     println(flag2)
```

}

in above code i have declared 2 type of boolean **Explicit** and **Implicit** declaration

for above code i would say expect following ouput :-

```
false and true 

true

false
```

but i'm getting following erroe :-
[image: error given by IDE]

can anyone explain where did i go wrong ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you must stringify your booleans explicitly. This is not PHP, you know :)

Comment: What the error message tells you, is kotlin failed to find such overload of operator `+` where left part is a boolean and right is a string.

Comment: also `var flag2: =false` is invalid code, this won't even compile.

Comment: In addition to the comments above, you should use string interpolation, not concatenation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that compiler error, change this:

```
println(flag2 + "and " + flag1)
```

to this:

```
println("$flag2 and $flag1")
```

Kotlin is strongly typed language and you can't use plus operator on String and Boolean types.

But you can use string interpolation, with $ operator inside a string literal.

You could also make it compile with overloaded plus operator on the Boolean type by adding this:

```
operator fun Boolean.plus(s: String): String {
    return this.toString() + s
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java, it performs [string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894892/primitive-boolean-to-string-concatenation-conversion) when you concatenate a string with any type of object. For example,

```
System.out.println(true + " and false");    //Output: true and false
```

In Kotlin, string conversion doesn't exist. Alternatively, you may use [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates) for that.

```
println("$flag2 and $flag1")
```

Besides, since Kotlin's String class provide `plus(Any?)` function which receives any type as parameter, so the following line of code is still valid:

```
println("$flag2 and " + flag1)
```

Here is a [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/string-concat-with-integer-implicit-type-conversion/5419) on this design.

Comment: Or `println("" + flag2 + " and " + flag1)`